# Hybrid Connection multiple calls fail sometimes

Tags: oracle, azure, entity-framework-6

I have some troubles with my Azure Hybrid Connection. I have created a Azure Hybrid Connection between my OnPremise Oracle and Azure Website.

I have a WEB API App hosted as Azure Website. I have two APIs which fetch Data from the OnPremise Hybrid Connection.

If I make calls to both APIs at same time. One of the APIs most of the time fails (but not always). The error is following.

I do that on localhost I don't get any errors. I think that the error might be  Hybrid Connection related.

```
   An unhandled exception occurred. System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-03135: Connection lost contact ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException: ORA-03135: Connection lost contact ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
```